# How to know if a function has asymptotes

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Let's say we have the function :
$$y = \frac{x}{x^2+1}$$

I want to know if the function has vertical or horizontal asymptotes what is the algorithm to find if a function has asymptotes?

I know that the function has a local maximum at x=1 and a local minimum at x =-1 and it is symmetrical about the origin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has no vertical asymptotes, since there is no value $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that the limit of the function when $x$ approaches $a$ by the left or right is $\pm\infty$. The horizontal asymptote is the line $y=0$, since $$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x) =0.$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

- For horizontal asymptote :

If $\lim_{x\to \pm \infty }f(x)=\ell\in \mathbb R$, then, the line of equation $y=\ell$ is an horizontal asymptote.

- For vertical asymptote :

If there is $a\in \mathbb R$ s.t. $\lim_{x\to a^\pm} f(x)=\pm \infty $, then, the line of equation $x=\pm a$ is a vertical asymptote.